# Using descriptor causes Recursion Error: maximum recursion depth

Tags: python-3.x

Why does the usage of this descriptor cause Recursion Error?

```py
class Capitalized:
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance.name = value.upper()
           
class Person(object):
    name = Capitalized()
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.name} is {self.age} yr(s) old'
        
Person('dave', 25) # !Error
```

I get the following error:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

However, if I don't use `name = Capitalized()`, everything is fine (well, except that I can't use the descriptor). I am using python `v3.9.1`.

Answer (score 1):

You are constructing your classes in a way, so that `__set__` is calling itself again and again. `instance.name = value.upper()` is calling `Capitalized.__set__`

To avoid this you may use a private attribute like this:

```
class Capitalized:
        
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print('setting')
        instance._name = value.upper()
        
    def __get__(self, instance, objtype=None):
        return instance._name
```

Change `instance._name` to `instance.name` and you will see the infinite recursion.